# Why does segmentation fault occur when pushing to pointer of vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, segmentation-fault

I am trying to learn c++ and wanted to write a simple program to explore the use of vectors and pointer. When I try to run a simple program that uses this function a segmentation fault occur. When I change

```
std::vector<string> *data;
```

to

```
std::vector<string> data;
```

and change the '->push_back()' to a '.push_back()' it runs fine.

```
int simple_tokenizer(string s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::vector<string> *data;
    string word;
    //char delimiter = ',';
    while(getline(ss,word, ',')) {
        //cout << "charsplit" << word << endl;
        data->push_back(word);
    }
    return 0;//data;

}
```

Comment: Before using '*data' you should allocate/create a vector.

Comment: thanks for you help! should that actual vector replace std::vector<string> ?

Comment: Every time you use pointers ( <type>* ) you need to allocate/create (i.e. `new <type>`).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. I believe you would be just fine with `std::vector<string> data;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is generation a segmentation fault because you didn't allocate memory for your pointer.

```
int simple_tokenizer(string s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::vector<string> *data = new std::vector<string>();
    string word;
    //char delimiter = ',';
    while(getline(ss,word, ',')) {
        //cout << "charsplit" << word << endl;
        data->push_back(word);
    }
    return 0;//data;

}
```

Mind you you need to `delete` it once you are done using it, but really there is no point in allocated an `std::vector` dynamically, it will allocating everything needed within it, and you won't have to risk memory leaks because you won't have to chase it around with `delete` everywhere.

Comment: thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was trying to do. I realise there is no real point to it I was just trying to explore how pointers work. When you say delete would this just be via


delete std::vector<string> data; ?

Comment: Nope, just `delete data`